# Delphi desktop sharing

Tags: delphi, remote-desktop, rdp

I want to provide desktop sharing from within my Delphi application (remote viewing essentially).

In my research I have found C# source that does exactly what I want: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/03/23/writing-a-desktop-sharing-application.aspx

However I cannot find any reference to accessing rdpcomapi (rdpencom.dll) from Delphi. 
Can anyone point me to a Delphi interface to this COM object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the required Delphi interfaces by importing the COM type library for rdpencom.dll. In Delphi XE2, select the `View | Registered Type Libraries` menu, sort by "Description" and find the `rdpcomapi 1.0 Type Library`. Click `Import` on the toolbar to create the Delphi interface/type definitions.